# Multi-level parsing pattern to avoid duplicates

Tags: python, scrapy

I am navigating the categories of an e-retail store. Usually, there is a category link, which I follow to get to a list of products in that category. But some categories have additional sub-categories so I have an additional parse method to check if that is the case.

To represent the problem, parse yields a request, which is checked by the parse_second callback. If the the response to parse_second is a category page it does some additional processing before yielding the request to parse third, else it just forwards the response to parse_third.

```
def parse(self, response):
    ...
    yield Request(some_url, callback=self.parse_second)

def parse_second(self, response):
    ...
    #check if category page or listing page
    if is_category_page:
        #do some processing to get new_url
        yield Request(new_url, callback=self.parse_third)

    else:
         #just forward the previous request to a new callback
         yield Request(response.url, callback=self.parse_third)

def parse_third(self, response):
    ...
```

As a result, many of the requests are not being processed in `parse_third` because they are duplicate, i.e they've already been crawled by the `parse_second` callback.

I believe I can set param `dont_filter=True` in the Request object but it sounds more like a patch. Is there a good or accepted method to avoid this problem? I believe it must be a common pattern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dont_filter = True` is correct.

even looking at http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/settings.html#dupefilter-class and changing the way fingerprint are set to say yes/no this is a duplicate, that won't solve your issue.

Might be handy to have a ALLOW_DUPLICATES = # of duplicates allowed

Answer (score 1):

You can call `parse_xxx()` directly instead of `yield Request()`:

```
def parse(self, response):
    ...
    for i in self.parse_second(response):
        yield i
```

Comment: i don't get it. Could you explain?

Comment: @pad You don't need to `yield a Request` to get the same `response` that you already got.